# Suitable bicycle grease for aluminium and steel materials?

Tags: seatpost, steel, aluminum, grease

I hope you enjoy your day.

A few days after of using my bike I have some troubling feeling about it. I can hear a cracking sound or something similar, and on the internet I found out the cause.

I concluded and was hoping that the problem is only the seatpost.
But I've found another one. When I pedal, the bike also create a cracking sound, especially when pedalling too hard. I hope that with a little bit of cleaning and lubrication I would be able to fix that.

But sadly again, sometimes I also hear the sound when I brake too hard.
I hope it's gone.
For now, my seatpost is slipping when I seat on it.

My questions is: since my bike frame is made of an aluminium, what kind of grease should I use?
In the shop that I visited only "Ceramic" or "Teflon" were available. Which one is most suitable? Please remember that my frame is aluminium and the seatpost is steel.

Which grease is suitable for two different materials, in my case aluminium and steel?

I found those on the internet and they are available in my local bike shop:

1. http://www.finishlineusa.com/products/bicycle-greases/ceramic-grease-advanced-bearing-lubrication
2. http://www.finishlineusa.com/products/bicycle-greases/premium-grease-made-with-teflon-fluoropolymer

Little hard to find:

3. https://www.parktool.com/product/anti-seize-compound-asc-1

Which priorities should I take into consideration given the choices above?

Thanks

Comment: Steel seat posts are very unusual, what kind of bike do you have?

Comment: @ojs, Forgive Me, I have xc sport mtb bike. I check again on the specification there is no type of material used on my seatpost, but the type is Entity Sport a trademark of Entity from Australia, I think these the seatpost that I used [seatpost](http://www.entitycycling.com/entity-sport-mtb-seatpost-offset)

Comment: @ojs that depends how old/cheap your bike is. I've got a steel seatpost on a steel MTBSO I use as a beater, and I've got another in the garage from its predecessor - a '92 Raleigh no-sus MTB.

Comment: Use a magnet to distinguish steel from other metals.

Comment: actually, the bike is a polygon brand from Indonesia, the price is around $221,75, and I think it's still a new product, [the bike](https://www.polygonbikes.com/id/shop/sepeda/cascade-4/)

Comment: @Carel, ok I will try it soon

Comment: A bike that creaks when braking sounds really dangerous. Try to exactly locate its source, because that may hint at a cracked frame. And you absolute do not want to be riding a cracked frame!

Comment: @cmaster I already checked the bike, but I don't see the crack, maybe there any suggestion for me what should I do ? or the sound is not crack sound, maybe the other but the sound looks similar?

Comment: I'm not sure we are talking about the same kind of sound. When you say "cracking sound" I translated into "creaking sound" (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/creak), because that is what you may usually hear with a bike. A creaking invariably means that parts are rubbing against each other which shouldn't. (Metal on metal!) The word cracking sound is not normally used, but if it is used, it would mean a *single* sharp "tack" or "bang". Creaking is similar, but many small "tack"s in quick succession. Have I misinterpreted you? Can you describe the sound in more detail?

Comment: @cmaster sometimes I hear that kind of sound when I'm the first-time seat on the bike, like in the morning after cool night, also when I push handlebar too hard and on high speed then I brake suddenly. But when deliberately push the handlebar and brake hard, the sound not come.
I guess when I heard that kind of sound is very thin, but it is heard when silent. Probably the sound almost sounds like this ["similar sound example"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfnirI_M_QM). I hope this can be solved only with simple care :)

Comment: I would describe the sound in the video as clicking sound. That's much, much less dangerous than a creaking or cracking sound. So far, so good :-) Nevertheless, some part of your bike seems to have a bit of play that it shouldn't have. I guess you are braking with your front wheel? In that case, parts you may want to analyze for unwanted play are the mounts of the brake (dangerous if that's the reason), the steering bearings (can you move the fork relative to the frame?), the stem (if it's adjustable, check the joint), and the handle bars (very unlikely to be the cause).

Comment: @cmaster I was a little tingled by the word "much less dangerous", but it made me search on the internet, it compares something further, and in this context "much less dangerous" it means it is was far from danger right? thank god for that :D. 
yes, you are right, I brake with the front brake. but if some of the possibilities that you describe there is no problem, then means it's fine?

Comment: Yes "much less dangerous" is much better than "dangerous", because "dangerous" itself is bad. If you can't localize the problem, that simply means that you can't localize the problem. It does not say anything about the problem itself. It may be fine, or it may not, you simply don't know. Another thing that you might want to check is the axle of the wheel itself: Grab the front tire near the fork and see if you can push/pull it sideways relative to the fork. If there is more movement than that from the flexing spokes, it's either a loose wheel, or too much play in the bearings.

Comment: @cmaster I’m so grateful for your help. It made me easier to identify the care of my bike. I will try to try it soon, I hope my bike will be fine. I really appreciate I hope this can also be useful for others. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic bicycle grease such as the Finishline Teflon grease is acceptable for seatposts, pedal threads, bolt in bottom brackets etc., and all bolts and threaded fasteners.

It's main use is for lubricating bearings but it does work for assembling components, preventing them from corroding together or creaking.

Comment: What about the other grease options? I can use it too?

Comment: @Bagusa4 That other grease is specifically for lubricating bearings, I would not use it on the seatpost. I imagine it's somewhat more expensive.

Comment: The word "I would not use it on the seatpost", it is not good because will make it worse or because it's just more expensive? 
Because I would like to use that to the other components too, I think I will like to choose the best one :)

Comment: @Bagusa4 there is no ‘best’ grease. An expensive grease designed for bearings won’t perform better than the basic stuff on the seat post.

Comment: So the conclusion is the expensive grease just will worth better on the bearing but not the basic stuff like seatpost, but I can choose the expensive one for the better used on the bearing and can be used it too on the seatpost without different? 
because in my opinion, it would be better when I choose grease that can be used for all components and get maximum performance :)

Comment: @Bagusa4 It does not sound like you are at the point of servicing your own bearings so just get the basic grease.

Comment: I need it just for in case, because when I hand over the bike to be repaired by a technician in my shop, they don't give good grease to the bearing like in "front and rear hubs, bottom bracket, fork tube, etc"

Comment: thank you for your participation and good advice :), I have a choice now :)

Answer (score 2):

After thinking longer about feeling unwell. I research little bit longer about what is the suitable grease for seatpost, especially on aluminum material.

I found out on the internet talking about using a grease on the bicycle. In there, they said about do not using the grease on the seatpost because can cause damage on the bicycle. The reason is that grease can make the seatpost slip and must tighten the clamp more and more which can cause bad for the bicycle or cause the crack sound because over tighten on the clamp.

The advice they have given is used like "Assembly Paste", like this product ["Anti Seize Assembly Lubricant"](http://www.finishlineusa.com/products/specialty-products/anti-seize-assembly-lubricant), which specifically designed for use such as in the seatpost area. Because the cause of problems in seatpost is corrosion, erosion, abrasions, due to large friction which results in changes in size at seatpost, and then makes the other problems such as crack sound and slip.

Then the result is "Assembly Paste" prevent all the causes, and I will go for it.

The references

1. 
2. 

Thanks to all who have participated. I hope this can be a useful reference.